# Is it possible to automatically define this function for any arbitrary data type?

Tags: haskell

Mind the definition of the `fold` function below:

```
data T = A | B T | C T T
fold up2 up1 up0 down accum x   = dig x accum where
    dig (C a b) accum           = up2 C a b accum (dig a (down (C a b) accum)) (dig b (down (C a b) accum)) 
    dig (B a) accum             = up1 B a accum (dig a (down (B a) accum))
    dig A accum                 = up0 A accum
```

This function as a very regular way to be defined, but it depends on the maximum number of recursive branches a data constructor of that type has. That is, T has a constructor with 2 recursion points `C T T`, so "fold" receives three "up" arguments. If `C T T` was not part of the type, then the definition of fold would take one less argument:

```
data T = A | B T
fold up1 up0 down accum x = dig x accum where
    dig (B a) accum = up1 B a accum (dig a (down (B a) accum))
    dig A accum     = up0 A accum
```

My question is wether it is possible to create a definition of `fold` automatically using `deriving`.

Comment: Very regular? Honestly it looks very crazy to me. Signature plz! Oh my. `fold :: ... -> ((T->...->T)->a->...->q-> z->...-> z) -> ... -> ((T->T->T->T)->a->b->c->q->z->z->z->z) -> ((T->T->T)->a->b->q->z->z->z) -> ((T->T)->a->q->z->z) -> (T->q->z) -> T -> z`, is that right?

Comment: `deriving` might be insufficient, since it works only for a few selected classes. Maybe Template Haskell can help here, instead?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, the function itself is complicate, but it is regular in a sense there is an algorithm to define it given a data-structure. Also, as much as the function looks crazy, it generalizes every possible recursive algorithm on the datatype, so defining recursive functions become much cleaner as there is now a separation of navigation and data processing.

Comment: Uninformed questions: don't general folds usually take one function per constructor? Also, why do you pass the constructors as arguments to the `up` functions?

Comment: @duplode because the general folds aren't able to encode certain functions. For example, Haskell's fold is not able to modify the tags of a node, just its contents. [This blog post has a solution for that.](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2014/03/20/recursion-schemes-functors) The version posted here is even stronger, as you can create a recursive function that returns an arbitrary type (say, a function that iterates through a datatype and returns True if certain node is present). I believe is not possible in other ways (but would love to see a better solution!).

Comment: Oh and the reason I separated the constructors and values is that it makes some functions much cleaner. For example, try to define an identity recursive function without that separation. It will become clear. You have to write every pattern matching once again to recover the constructors, so, for long datatypes, you get a 12-liner instead of a 3-liner.

Comment: "[A] function that iterates through a datatype and returns True if certain node is present." Maybe I'm missing something, but that seems possible with a plain catamorphism. I wrote a [gist demo](https://gist.github.com/duplode/a97c7640cb7b8ea74e73); is it relevant?

Comment: Yes but that fold requires a function for each sum type... when you have a big/complex datatype you end up having to write a dozens of lines per function using the fold, so that doesn't improve much the situation ...

Comment: But your fold also requires one up-function per constructor, in addition to `down` and `accum`; furthermore the up-functions have rather more complicated signatures. (I'm not trying to be argumentative; it's just that, as you are certainly aware of, if you find you can do with the usual recursion schemes there will be both theory and libraries to help you.)

Comment: That is not true, it only requires 3 up functions, as long as you have no data constructor with more than 2 recursion points. So, for example, when your type is something like `data T = A | B T | C T T | D | E T | F T T | G T T | H T | I | J | K | L T T` (which could be the case, for example, of a DSL with a complex grammar) and so on, you can still have a short recursive function that targets a specific constructor. So that is the point of the question, can you make that generic?

Comment: Your data structure has no data, only shape. There isn't much to fold here. Adding data, your second example `data T = A | B T` becomes `data T a = A | B a (T a)` which is just a list in disguise. (Without data it's just a natural number). But your function that "folds" it doesn't look like the list fold which we all know and love. And your main example doesn't look like something from `Data.Foldable` or `Data.Functor.Foldable`. Can you give a real-life example that demonstrates necessity of your style of fold?

Comment: I could, but I fear this is not the place for this. The question is not about the validation of the style, it is about a technical problem.

Comment: "Yes, the function itself is complicate, but it is regular in a sense there is an algorithm to define it given a data-structure". Do you know what the algorithm is? Because it is far from obvious to me.

Comment: You'll probably get somewhere by computing the base functor of `T` and doing folds there. Things like `Traversable` will become handy.

Answer (score 1):

Defining this via `deriving` alone can be a bit of a pain. But if you know the algorithm, then the `Generics` package can let you write it, and you can then use default signatures to "autoderive" an instance with slightly different but still nice syntax.

Two libraries that might serve you well in this regard are: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop

Comment: Uh... looking at this question now makes me realize how much I've learned on those months. :)